# Combining product flavors from two modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have a project with two flavors dimensions. One is endpoint and it is used for switching prod/staging. Other is site and it is for different color schemes and data sources. There are about 20 site flavors and only two endpoints. So, flavors configuration looks like this:

```
flavorDimensions "site", "endpoint"

productFlavors {
    pro {
        dimension 'endpoint'
    }

    staging {
        dimension 'endpoint'
    }

    site1 {
        dimension 'site'
        applicationId "co.site1"
    }

    …

    site20 {
        dimension 'site'
        applicationId "co.site20"
    }
}
```

Now I need to move API requests to separate module. So, it'll be fine to move endpoints configuration to this module. So, app flavors should be:

In app:

```
productFlavors {
    site1 {
        applicationId "co.site1"
    }

    …

    site20 {
        applicationId "co.site20"
    }
}
```

In API library:

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
    }

    staging {
    }
}
```

But how to combine them? Earlier I could easily get builds like App-proSite15. How to configure the same with two modules?

Currently my solution is to leave configuration as is. I have only string resources in endpoint flavors, and can access them in API module by string name via `getIdentifier`

Comment: So found anything ? i'm looking for same thing?

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt Unfortunately I haven't found better solution than keeping all flavor dimensions in one module